# How to create a System.Diagnostics.Process array

Tags: c#, exit-code, system.diagnostics

I want to call three of the same EXE at the same time, and I expect three return value when they all terminated, Here's how I got so far:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = MyEXEPath;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       p.StartInfo.Arguments =  para1[i] + " " + para2[i];
       p.Start();
       Console.WriteLine("Start run");
    }
    p.WaitForExit();
    int result = p.ExitCode;
    Console.WriteLine("Return info:" + results);  //Problem: I can only get the last return value
```

You can see I only got one return value, not three, so I wonder if I can do this:

```
    int[] results = new int[3];
    System.Diagnostics.Process p[] = new System.Diagnostics.Process()[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       p[i].StartInfo.FileName = MyEXEPath;
       p[i].StartInfo.Arguments = para1[i] + " " + para2[i];
       p[i].Start();
       Console.WriteLine("Start run");
       p[i].EnableRaisingEvents = true;
       p[i].Exited += (sender, e) =>
       {
          results[i] = p[i].ExitCode;
          Console.WriteLine("Return info:" + results[i]);
       };
    }
    while(results[0] != 0 && results[1] != 0 && results[2] != 0 )
    {
        break;  //all EXEs ternimated,  break and continue my job
    }
```

Sure it is compile fail with `System.Diagnostics.Process p[] = new System.Diagnostics.Process()[3];`
So how can I fixed it or there's another way?

Comment: `var p = new [] { new Process(), new Process(), new Process() };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, you would have to remove the `()` and then create new process for each one:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = new System.Diagnostics.Process[3];
p[0] = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p[1] = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p[2] = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
```

Alternatively, you can use a C# array initializer and short-hand (implicit array initialization). In the following code I would use a `using System.Diagnostics;` at the top of the file to reduce the namespace:

```
var p = new [] { new Process(), new Process(), new Process() };
```

Which both creates the array and initializes the elements.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, if you change your solution a bit, it'll do whatever you're expected.

I changed a bit on your solution and it worked correctly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"d:\\text{i}.txt";
        p.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Start run");
        p.WaitForExit();
        int result = p.ExitCode;
        Console.WriteLine("Return info:" + $"text{i}.txt created successfully!");
    }

    p.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "d:";
    p.Start();
}
```